# Android - Center an ImageView on edge of layout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am using ConstraintLayout and I want to center an ImageView on the edge of the layout like this image:
[imageview centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFYHo.png)

How can I achieve this by using ConstraintLayout without using elevation (I don't know how to deal with elevation in pre-Lollipop devices).

Here is my code so far:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="190dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="#eee"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:id="@+id/main_ride_finished_container"
    >


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_driver_enroute_BS_driverImage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        />
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what you try so far post the code here

Comment: @akhilesh0707 i added the code sample i am usin

Comment: [This](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator) will lead you to [this](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do place a view centered on the edge of a layout by using the appropriate constraints. In the following simple example the `ImageView` is constrained to the start and end of the enclosing container to center it horizontally. The image view's top and bottom are constrained to the bottom of the inner layout to center on the bottom. This is how `ConstraintLayout` deals with "impossible" constraints. See the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#CenteringPositioning).

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/innerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/innerLayout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```